# How can I check a Java library's dependencies against the appengine whitelist?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, compatibility, gae-whitelist

I want to use the SIFWorks ADK, a java library, with my appengine project.  It's a complex library with 700 classes.  I can get a sample application to run on the appengine development environment.  I don't want a surprise later in development that some class I need to use, but failed to test, has a dependency not on the whitelist.

I used DependencyFinder to generate a list of dependencies, and it produces a huge list of classes, and also things like `java.util.*`, which I can't check against the whitelist directly.

What's the best way to ensure a complex library will be fully compatible with appengine?

Comment: If you've already got a list of dependencies, why can't you just compare it to the whitelist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this project: 
http://www.ltech.com/cloud/google-app-engine/java-compatibility-analyzer
It will scan your class files and check for dependencies against the whitelist.